# Error while adding dataset, Oject name allready iin database

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services, report

I have a piece of code that I put into a few Temp tables that I run in SSRS as a Data Set.

I'm having trouble getting this to work as it keeps saying that the object name already exists? This runs fine in management studio but falls over in Visual Studios.

I have 2 other reports that are identical that look at a different addresses and these work fine.

I can put each bit of Code separately into SSRS and it works but putting it in as a temp table format seems not to work, I have also tired this as a proc.

```
  There is already an object named '#Recordsimported30BL' in the database.
```

Comment: Using #Table? If you are using it then make sure you drop it once execution over - so in the end of store procedure Drop table #Recordsimported30BL

Comment: I have tried dropping before and after.

Answer (score 1):

Why should you put first the data in a temp table? if you're script has a `select into #temp` table then you have another select after it that is pointing to the #temp table. Just add a `drop table #temp` at the end of your script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in your code to make sure the table is dropped:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Recordsimported30BL') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Recordsimported30BL;
```

But please check your code carefully to make sure there is no valuable data in the table at that point.

Temporary tables are automatically dropped at the end of session. That might explain why your code works fine in SQL Management Studio. Your program on the other hand might use one persistent session to run multiple reports. That's where you might end up with a temporary table from the previous run still present in the tempdb when you try to create it anew.

...and @[Aldrin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37458548/5690722) is right. Do make sure you `DROP` your temp tables when they are no longer needed.

Comment: Looks like you've got a deadlock on this table. Something else is using it. Check for recursion in your code.

Comment: To overcome the issue one might try generating temporary table names dynamically.